# dijkstras algorithm doesn't find the actual shortest path

Tags: python, algorithm, dijkstra

I am trying to implement dijkstras algorithm  in python using three dictionaries. However, I am not getting the true shortest path to Piano from Book. My implementation doesn't update the parent of `Piano` even after a shorter path to it from node `Drum set`.

Here is my output:
`parents-{'Poster': 'Book',
 'Rare LP': 'Book',
 'Piano': 'Bass guitar',
 'Bass guitar': 'Rare LP',
 'Drum set': 'Rare LP'}
processed-['Poster', 'Rare LP', 'Bass guitar', 'Drum set', 'Piano']
costs-{'Poster': 0, 'Rare LP': 5, 'Bass guitar': 15, 'Drum set': 20, 'Piano': 20}`

Desired_result-
parents-{'Poster': 'Book',
 'Rare LP': 'Book',
 'Piano': 'Drum set',
 'Bass guitar': 'Rare LP',
 'Drum set': 'Rare LP'}
costs-{'Poster': 0, 'Rare LP': 5, 'Bass guitar': 15, 'Drum set': 20, 'Piano': 10}

Here is my implementation-

```
import math
# the graph
graph = {'Book':{'Poster':0, 'Rare LP':5}, 'Poster':{'Bass guitar':30, 'Drum set':35},
         'Rare LP':{'Bass guitar':15, 'Drum set':20}, 'Bass guitar':{'Piano':20},
         'Drum set':{'Piano':10},'Piano':{}}

# the costs table
costs = {'Poster':0, 'Rare LP':5, 'Bass guitar':math.inf, 'Drum set':math.inf, 'Piano':math.inf}

# the parents table
parents = {'Poster':'Book', 'Rare LP':'Book', 'Piano':''}


processed = []

def find_lowest_cost_node(costs):
    lowest_cost = math.inf
    lowest_cost_node = None
    # Go through each node.
    for node in costs:
        cost = costs[node]
        # If it's the lowest cost so far and hasn't been processed yet...
        if cost < lowest_cost and node not in processed:
            # ... set it as the new lowest-cost node.
            lowest_cost = cost
            lowest_cost_node = node
    return lowest_cost_node

# Run till all nodes are processed
while len(processed) < len(graph)-1:
    lowest_cost_node = find_lowest_cost_node(costs)

    #Loop through neighbours of the current lowest_cost_node
    for node in graph[lowest_cost_node].keys():


        if costs[node] > costs[lowest_cost_node] + graph[lowest_cost_node][node]:
            costs[node] = graph[lowest_cost_node][node]
            parents[node] = lowest_cost_node
    processed.append(lowest_cost_node)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part looks suspicious:

```
if costs[node] > costs[lowest_cost_node] + graph[lowest_cost_node][node]:
        costs[node] = graph[lowest_cost_node][node]
```

The assigned cost does not include the original cost of the node.

Try:

```
if costs[node] > costs[lowest_cost_node] + graph[lowest_cost_node][node]:
        costs[node] = costs[lowest_cost_node] + graph[lowest_cost_node][node]
```